# Ansible lineinfile module syntax error when using multiple variables in string

Tags: windows, syntax, ansible

I have a few uses of lineinfile in my Ansible playbooks which work well, however my latest addition gives a syntax error and I can't figure out how to resolve it.

Working code:

```
  community.windows.win_lineinfile:
    path: C:\PowerTools\Config\Config.psd1
    backrefs: yes
    regex: '^(.*)apiBase(.*)$'
    line: '    apiBase            = "http://{{ app_server }}/dm-rest-services/api"'
```

Failing code:

```
  community.windows.win_lineinfile:
    path: C:\PowerTools\Config\Config.psd1
    backrefs: yes
    regex: '^(.*)connectionString(.*)$'
    line: '    connectionString   = "Data Source={{ db_server }},1433;Initial Catalog={{ db_name }};User Id={{ db_user }}; Password={{ dm_db_password['secrets'][0]['secret'] }}"'
```

I'm getting the below generic syntax error:

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'

The error appears to be in '/root/gitlab-ansible/roles/fico_etl/tasks/powertools.yml': line 25, column 152, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    regex: '^(.*)connectionString(.*)$'
    line: '    connectionString   = "Data Source={{ db_server }},1433;Initial Catalog={{ db_name }};User Id={{ db_user }}; Password={{ dm_db_password['secrets'][0]['secret'] }}"'
                                                                                                                                                       ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using single quotes (') around the entire line, but also within the line around `'secrets'` and `'secret'`.

In your case, you need to use double quotes around the whole line, and escape the double quotes within the line with a backslash

```yaml
  community.windows.win_lineinfile:
    path: C:\PowerTools\Config\Config.psd1
    backrefs: yes
    regex: '^(.*)connectionString(.*)$'
    line: "    connectionString   = \"Data Source={{ db_server }},1433;Initial Catalog={{ db_name }};User Id={{ db_user }}; Password={{ dm_db_password['secrets'][0]['secret'] }}\""
```