# How to replace all occurences of one word with another using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, ansible

I am trying to replace a tag value in a web.config file using Regex with ansible playbook.

This is my sample file.

```
TXWebSocketHandler="Data =localhost;Catalog Name=catalogname;User =user;key=key;
TXWebSocketHandler="Data =localhost;Catalog Name=catalogname;User =user;key=key;
TXWebSocketHandler="Data =localhost;Catalog Name=catalogname;User =user;key=key;
```

My Desired output should be

```
TXWebSocketHandler="Data =127.0.0.1;Catalog Name=catalogname;User =user;key=key;
TXWebSocketHandler="Data =127.0.0.1;Catalog Name=catalogname;User =user;key=key;
TXWebSocketHandler="Data =127.0.0.1;Catalog Name=catalogname;User =user;key=key;
```

All the localhost should be replaced as 127.0.0.1.

And the playbook I have used is

```
  - name: replace_config
    community.windows.win_lineinfile:
      path: 'D:\Apps\project\web.config'
      regexp: /localhost/g
      line: 127.0.0.1
```

For this I am getting a output like,

```
TXWebSocketHandler="Data =localhost;Socket Name=Socketname;User =user;key=key;
TXWebSocketHandler="Data =localhost;Socket Name=Socketname;User =user;key=key;
TXWebSocketHandler="Data =localhost;Socket Name=Socketname;User =user;key=key;
127.0.0.1
```

Substitution value that I am adding is not replaced in localhost, but it is getting added in end of the file. when I try in any of [regex generator](https://regex101.com/r/If8oqS/1) this works fine like I wanted.

Is it an issue with regex or am I missing any argument in this ansible playbook? Please suggest some method to replace all occurences of one word with another .

Comment: the [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_lineinfile_module.html#examples) don't seem to have global modifier that I can see, have you tried `regexp: 'localhost'` and `line: '127.0.0.1'`

Comment: It might be worth trying the [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/replace_module.html) module. I know it works on GNU/Linux, but you could try on Windows as well.

Comment: @depperm I have tried that, It didn't worked either. I am getting the same result.

Comment: @seshadri_c Have tried that too, Since it's a python module it didn't worked as well. There is no module as win_replace which would have been very much useful.

Comment: What exactly was the outcome with built-in _replace_ module? Python works also on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

#### Single-line restriction

The module [*community.windows.win_lineinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_lineinfile_module.html#parameter-backrefs) seems to work on single lines only:

> Ensure a particular line is in a file, or replace an existing line using a back-referenced regular expression

From [Synopsis](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_lineinfile_module.html#synopsis):

> This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only.

Still you could use [`backrefs: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_lineinfile_module.html#parameter-backrefs) to replace a single line, see the docs (restriction emphasized in bold):

> If the `regexp` does match, the **last matching line** will be replaced by the expanded line parameter.

See also
[Ansible lineinfile module syntax error when using multiple variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282791/ansible-lineinfile-module-syntax-error-when-using-multiple-variables-in-string).

In your playbook:

```yaml
  - name: replace_config
    community.windows.win_lineinfile:
      path: 'D:\Apps\project\web.config'
      backrefs: true
      regexp: '^(.*)localhost(.*)$'
      line: '$1 127.0.0.1 $2'
```

This should replace the matched `localhost` with the loopback IP `127.0.0.1`, and set the captured parts before (backreferenced by $1) and after (backreferenced by $2) back in.

Note: If it worked, try to remove the surrounding spaces from IP-address.

#### Replace as built-in module

As [seshadri_c suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146364/how-to-replace-all-occurences-of-one-word-with-another-using-regular-expression/75147464?noredirect=1#comment132608771_75146364):
[*ansible.builtin.replace*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html) module can be used:

> Replace all instances of a particular string in a file using a back-referenced regular expression

See [Synopsis](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#synopsis):

> This module will replace all instances of a pattern within a file.

From the docs, adapt the first example "Replace old hostname with new hostname" to your use-case:

```yaml
- name: Replace old hostname with new hostname (requires Ansible >= 2.4)
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: D:/Apps/project/web.config
    regexp: '(.*)localhost(.*)$'
    replace: '\1 127.0.0.1 \2'
```

Note: I replaced the backslashes (Windows path-separator) to forward-slashes (safer with Python). The added spaces after back-ref `\1`
and before `\2` might be removed (not sure if it works because numbers of back-ref and IP-address could collide). See the other example in docs "Explicitly specifying named matched groups" for another way.

Comment: This has replaced only the last matching localhost. Can we add /g in this regex? how can we do this kindly suggest.

Comment: @Esennin, this restriction was stated multiple times in the docs. To answer your question about the "global" flag or option `/g`, please see the module's docs: "Uses .NET compatible regular expressions;". [Regex Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) are supported by .NET, but  not inside the expression here.